# Autocorrelation at lag 1 but scatterplot shows no linear relationship

Tags: time-series, correlation, linear-model, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I have a time series consisting of 490 days and for each day I have the residual of a forecasting model. I wanted to check if the residuals somehow correlate and calculated the ACF at lag 1 which is `acf(1)=0.42` 
Here is the ACF plot:
[image: ACF]

Now I wanted to check the linear relationship between lag=0 (denoted as `x1` in the scatterplot) and lag=1 (`x2` in the scatterplot) so I plotted a scatterplot, but I don't see any linear relationship. Why do I have a correlation of 0.42 at lag 1 but I don't see the linearity between lag 0 and 1?

Am I missing a point here?

Update: I uploaded a CSV file with the time series [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8TUeOP-nzuqVndDOXZpdW1zV1VkQWtmM2dWT2RDWGprc3RF/view?usp=drivesdk)

[image: Scatterplot]

Comment: The green line has pretty much the 0.42 slope you see in the acf. That seems too match actually quite well.  Maybe you expected this to be more clearly on a line, rather than a "blob" of seemingly independent data points? Probably a robust fit (rlm()) would reduce the slope of green line and be closer to your visual assessment.

Comment: Can you comment about what the axis exactly mean?

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg: I tried rlm() and plotted the residuals vs fitted plot https://i.imgur.com/3hIGRtl.png  - how can i interprete the red line? as a comparison, this is the residuals vs fitted plot of lm(): https://i.imgur.com/F7m3dyQ.png

Comment: @user1420303: Do you mean the scatterplot? if yes, then x1 consists of timeseries with lag 0 and x2 is the "shifted" timeseries of lag=1. (as mentioned my initial timeseries has 490 values. Hence for the comparison, i create two "new" timeseries. The first one (x1) consists of values between 1:489 and the second one (x2) consists of values 2:490)

Comment: There are other effects that are masking  your "view" . Daily,weekly.holiday.monthly to name a few and possibly level shifts or local time trends AND definitely anomalies. The only time your approach would confirm the .42 is if there were no other (significant) effects. If you post your data in a csv file I will try and help further. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+daily+sales+data for more info on modelling daily data.

Comment: @IrishStat i uploaded the data in a csv file, updated the main post. It contains 497 days, of residuals taken at 12:00 am. The original time series is 497*48 periods (half hourly data) long, but i am interested in daily periodic effects at 12:00, so i am only looking the residual at 12:00. FYI.

Comment: what is the start date ?

Comment: it's the 01.10.2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upon receipt of the 497 daily values I obtained a plot [image] which supported my "guess" that there were other/latent factors present ( i.e. one clear level shift and one masked by anomalies ) . I used AUTOBOX my tool of choice and it identified a model  [image] [image] excerpting some pulse indicators. The final equation does indeed include an AR(1) and some possible seasonal/monthly dummies along with a bunch of anomalies.

The residual plot  [image]suggest sufficiency ( supported by the acf of the residuals) [image]

Hope this helps you and others regarding interpreting unconditional statistics either visual or written.

The forecast for the next 21 days is shown here
[image]